# Consulta multitabla sin claves foraneas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto (cuyo SGBD es MySQL) el cual cuenta con múltiples tablas que se relacionan con una sola.

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla país a la que se apunta al id de cada registro (es decir a un país) desde otras tablas, pero el campo desde el que se apunta en las otras tablas no es una foránea, simplemente contiene el id de dicho país.

El problema está en que no se como realizar la consulta para obtener la cantidad de registros que apuntan desde las otras tablas a la tabla países (la suma de todos los registros en las otras tablas) para así poder saber a cuantos registros apuntan a un país "duplicado".

¿Es posible hacer la consulta sin que haya claves foráneas?

Comment: Debes de subir código que hayas intentado, o al menos algo de información respecto a las tablas para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Sí es posible. Si al SGBD tú le dices `INNER JOIN ON t1.id_pais=t2.id_pais` él no te dirá: *no, esto no es clave foránea, no te daré los datos*, sino que te dará los datos que coincidan en ambas tablas. Ahora bien, las llaves foráneas sirven para optimizar las consultas, para controlar los duplicados o registros huérfanos, etc. La consulta funcionará, pero tu modelo de datos no está optimizado si no declaras las FK que necesite. Dicho esto, si necesitas cualquier ayuda debe ser sobre algo que hayas intentado. Otra cosa, en MySQL necesitas crear las tablas en `InnoDB` para trabajar con FK.